# Phonegap Android app icon refuses to update

Tags: android, cordova, icons

I've tried:

- changing the file at myapp/platforms/android/res/drawable/icon.png
- editing the  tag in www/config.xml
- minor sacrifices

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace all icon files in res folder.
Once you done, just clean your eclipse project and run.

Comment: check all the folders under res that have drawable as a prefix. Replace all icon.png files.

Answer (score 2):

If you have correctly updated your icon files in `platforms/ios/YourAppName/Resources/icons` and you still can't see the change then make sure you:

1. Completely remove the app from your device
2. In Xcode go to `Product > Clean` and then re run your app.

Answer (score 1):

although you accepted a different answer, that did not help me so for some of you reading this please note the following:

1. the accepted answer will work most probably only if u build ur
   app locally
2. u do not need to overwrite the default platform icons
       ... phonegap lets you overwrite everything from the config.xmlfile
3. you need to use something like this in you config.xml:

   ```
   <icon src="icon.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="img/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="img/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="img/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="img/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="img/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
   <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="img/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
   <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="img/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
   <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="img/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
   <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="img/icons/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
   <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="img/icons/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
   ```
4. **please note that the path is *img/bla-bla-bla* ... it can be whatever
   you want ... *BUT* ... that path it is relative to you *www* folder ...
   so it will actually map to *www/img/bla-bla-bla***

hope this helps someone ... i found it the hard way :)

Rares